# Do I need Terminal Server License in Server hosting Hyper-V Virtual Machines

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2, rdp

I recently installed a Windows Server 2008 R2.
I added the role "Hyper-V".
I imported a Virtual Machine (Another Windows Server 2008 R2).

The fact is that when I try to remote desktop inside the Virtual Machine, it gives me the error "The remote computer disconnected the session because of an error in the licensing protocol".

Later, I also installed Remote Desktop Role in the host server (not VM), and the problem continues.
I noted that I have a "grace" 120 days to use remote desktop, but I I still can't remote desktop into Virtual Machine. It keeps saying that an error in the licensing protocol..

Do I need to buy a license to use Administration only (1 user max) Remote Desktop to my Virtual Machine.

Thanks in advance,

Gonzalo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do **not** want to install the Remote Desktop Services role if you are only doing remote administration. The problem is most likely a DNS configuration error.

Comment: Jake, do you mean that I do not need Remote Desktop Services for accessing the Virtual Machine? Thanks Jake

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. You can have up to two simultaneous RDP connections to your 2008 R2 server for the purpose of remote administration. The Remote Desktop Services role provides the components for serving remote sessions to end-users (and requires licensing).

Comment: I uninstalled all Remote Desktop Services of the Server and the Virtual Machine and now is running. thank you!.